# Adding Parse.com Users with PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I am having trouble converting this curl to something that I can post with in PHP.
The API is as follows from Parse:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"username": "cooldude6", "password": "p_n7!-e8", "phone": "415-392-0202"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

In particular how would I pass line 5 an array of post values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php

$headers = array(
   'X-Parse-Application-Id' => ${APPLICATION_ID},
   'X-Parse-REST-API-Key', ${REST_API_KEY}
   'Content-type: application/json'
);

$data = array(
    'username' => "cooldude6",
    'password' => "p_n7!-e8",
    'phone': '415-392-0202',
    'postfield1' => $_POST['postfield1'],
    etc...
);

... connect to curl ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: This is the issue I'm having, its still not working for me, I am now getting {"error":"unauthorised"} - even though I have checked the ID and keys.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a complete example.
I am also getting {"error":"unauthorised"} when trying this.
IDs and keys are in place.

Comment: So I should go sign up for a dev key, read through a ton of docs, just to provide a 'complete example' for something that wasn't even within the scope of this question? Don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a PHP library for Parse.com wich handles all the REST Api functions with Parse.com https://github.com/FredvanRijswijk/parse.com-php-library

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "error unauthorized" I suspect you're passing the literal values ${APPLICATION_ID} and ${REST_API_KEY}.

Those are stand-in values for keys specific to your account. These keys are in your app dashboard. Recently, the documentation page at http://parse.com/docs/rest.html will  also automatically replace ${APPLIACTION_ID} and ${REST_API_KEY} with your real keys if you are logged in.